# What exception to throw when pre-requisite method was not called?

Tags: java, exception

I have a method `getUser` which retrieves a user from a database. The method demands that you verify that the user actually exists (via the `userExists(String username)` method.

If the `getUser` method is invoked and the user does not exist, I want to throw an unchecked exception, but which exception is the most appropriate here? I thought about `IllegalArgumentException`, but it doesn't feel completely right, as certain inputs may be okay in some cases, but not others - they are not strictly "illegal". Any suggestions?

Comment: But what if the user is deleted in the time between userExists and getUser is called? Can you guarantie that that is never a possible race condition?

Comment: @hlovdal, Then we would throw *another* exception for that exception.

Answer (score 13):

To me IllegalArgumentException means the argument is illegal and would always to illegal.  Th exception I would use is IllegalStateException to say the state of the object to check the user is not valid.

However you may have an exception which is specific enough you could create your own.

```
public class UsernameNotCheckedException extends IllegalStateException {
    public UsernameNotCheckedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This may make debugging things easier.

A `NumberFormatException` is a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException`.  Ifyou try to parse the number `12QW4` it will give you a `NumberFormatException` and there is nothing you can do to make this a valid argument later. i.e. it has nothing to do with the state of anything.

The Javadoc for `IllegalStateException` states.

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

Comment: Better and more complete than my answer, 1+. Will delete my answer.

Comment: Added your comment about making debugging easier. ;)

Comment: Disagree! According to JDK javadoc, `IllegalStateException` "Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time". In other words it's the state of the *object* whose method you called, not the parameters, that is incorrect. Another Exception would be a better choice.

Comment: @Bohemian, The username is correct, its the state of the object which is incorrect because `userExists` was not called for that user. The object has to change state to go from a before `userExists` state to after `userExists` was called state.

Comment: I agree with Bohemian. If the username being provided is not valid, then it's an invalid parameter, and an IllegalArgumentException should be thrown.

Comment: @Jesse, there is nothing wrong with the username.  The username can be called with a different method, which won't change the state of the `String` as its immutable.  Only the state of the object which is called means that method cannot be called with that username at that time.

Comment: @Bohemian, I think you may just be getting into subtle semantics about what "inappropriate time" means. It seems sensible enough to extend the use of "IllegalStateException" (possible with an actual class extension) to cover this case.

Comment: Based on the names of the method, I don't get the impression that calling userExists() changes the state of the object so that it's then OK to call getUser(). I think calling userExists() is just checking to see if the username is valid at this point in time, and if so then you can call getUser(). In any event, the hair-splitting between two different unchecked exception types is pointless, because only a programming error would cause this exception to be thrown, so it's not like it should be caught and handled differently.

Comment: It appears there is a view that it is the username which is illegal until the checkUser() method is called.  The problem with this is that the username is a String and it doesn't change state.  Its the object which is going to change state not the argument.

Comment: @Jesse, If it a programming error, I would suggest extending AssertionError. ;)

Answer (score 3):

`IllegalStateException` is not the right choice. `IllegalStateException` refers to the state of the object whose method has been called - ie the state of `this` is incorrect to be called as it has been. In your case `this` (ie the database server) is just fine, it's the *user* that is "incorrect".

`IllegalArgumentException` is the right choice - it's the *user* that is incorrect, not the server.

The other valid option is throwing a you own domain-specific exception, such as `UnknownUserException`, but if this case is "rare" or unexpected and unrecoverable, it's OK stick with `IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't throw any exception, and simply return `null`. Or I would throw a functional exception called `UserDoesNotExistException`.

Here's my reasoning: `IllegalStateException` is used when the user calls a method which is forbidden given the state of the object. Here, it's not the state of the object which causes the exception. It's the fact that the user doesn't exist in database.

You might argue that the user should have called `userExists` before, and that this method could even remember, using an instance field, that it has been called (with this argument), so that an `IllegalStateException` can be thrown by `getUser` without even going to the database.

But the problem here is that calling `userExists` before probably doesn't add anything: it will perform a query to check that a user exists, then `getUser` will perform a second query, and is not guaranteed to find the user, since another transaction might have removed it.

Comment: I get the impression from the OP that if userExists() returns true, then getUser() is guaranteed to return a result. In this case, it is clearly a programming error to call getUser() with a non-existent username, in which case an unchecked exception is the best choice. Returning null is just inevitably leading to a null pointer exception that will not clearly point to where the error occurred.

Comment: I got the inverse impression, because of the term "database" which makes me think that the user comes from a shared, concurrently accessed database rather than a private locked data structure. JPA's EntityManager.find method, which does what getUser does (in my understanding), returns null.

Comment: The application layer may very well prevent usernames from being changed or deleted, which would guarantee that a true result from userExists() will always give a non-null result from getUser(). In the case of EntityManager.find(), throwing an unchecked exception wouldn't make sense because at that layer, it has no knowledge of the business logic, and it might be perfectly valid to query for a non-existent record (which is exactly what happens in the userExists() method)

Comment: But your point is well-taken, that if it is possible for a username to be changed or deleted between the call to userExists() and getUser(), then an unchecked exception is not the right thing to do. In that case, I would prefer to throw a checked exception rather than return null.

Comment: I agree. But we don't have enough information to know and thus take the right decision.